# Is there ConcurrentLinkedHashSet for Java8?

Tags: java, collections

I saw the same question in 2011, i hope stuff changed since then, is there any ConcurrentLinkedHashSet for java 8? Couldn't find something in Guava nor in collections library.

Please do not suggest to wrap it with synchronized collections, as it loses the point.

Comment: What do you need specifically?  Often the reason there isn't something like this is because existing structures can do the job as efficiently.

Comment: What does this question even mean? if LinkedHashSet exists for a good reason, a concurrent version of it surely has a good reason to exist too.

Comment: In general, structures are built if there good use cases, not because it completes a set.  There's a good chance a Linked version of Map or Set can not as easily support concurrency.

Comment: Are there any specific properties that you need, besides the name “ConcurrentLinkedHashSet”? If you name them, it might turn out, that a collection type with these properties already exist…

Comment: @Holger - I would like a set, with a predictable iteration order (FIFO) that supports multiple threads actions and removal in O(1).

Comment: …and how much meaning has the insertion order in a *concurrent* scenario? The whole point of a `ConcurrentMap` is to allow *concurrent* access without enforcing an ordering. If you enforce an ordering, you are at what a synchronized collection does, which, as you say yourself, “loses the point”.

Comment: But what if there was an implementation like concurrentQueue for example that would expose its internal Node structure, and on removal instead of looking for the item you would already had the note, so you can just remove it in o (1). no?

Answer (score 1):

As what's on [Oracle Java 8 Concurrent doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html), there is no ConcurrentLinkedHashSet, concurrent collections do have following class

- [ConcurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)
- [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html)
- and more